# How to organise aggregates of inheriting objects in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's say you're constructing a domain model and you have the following requirements:

- There will be visitors who can read the data
- There will be publishers that can read and write the data
- There will be moderators that can read, write and delete the data

From an OOP perspective, you would create a base class that has everything common to each of the "actors" above. Then, I would create subclasses to represent each of the concrete types.
My question is this, in DDD world, how should I arrange my aggregates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use inheritance for that. Your requirements just need some user rights support. It's not even a DDD issue and what you're suggesting are not aggregates, but at most entities.

Anyway, the point is you'd have rights and groups (roles) which have specific rights. When you need to do something, you just check the current user's rights then proceed or forbid.

I'd use the same approach, no matter if I'd use DDD/OOP or not.

Comment: Well, that's what we figured out by talking me and my analyst.
I'm refactoring right now to only one Account aggregate.
Thanks for the clarifications! :)